# How can I find the file size of image which is read as QPixmap?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qpixmap

I get images from aws and assign them to QPixmap variables. I want to show their information as width height and file size. However I could not find a way to get file size of them. I converted them to QImage and used byteCount method however, although the file size of the image is 735 byte, it returns 3952 byte which is equal to width*height*4.

Comment: If you get the image data from aws, you already know the file size (i.e. `len(data)`).

Answer (score 1):

When you load image into `QPixmap` or `QImage`, it is converted from file format to internal representation. Because of that, `QImage.byteCount()` returns number of bytes used to store image. As you already mentioned, it is equals to width*height*4. Here, digit `4` is color depth (bytes per pixel). You can get it via `QImage.depth()` method. Note that it will return number of bits, so you have to divide it by 8 to get bytes.

So, if you want to get file size, you can either use `len(data)` (as suggested by ekhumoro) or load it to `QFile` and call `size()` (if you have/save it on hard drive).